# When building NestJS, environment variables are not defined on a particular controller

Tags: build, nestjs

App.module defines environment variables to be used globally.
For other controllers, environment variables are well applied when building.
Only a specific controller (user.controller) is not defined.
Instead, call user.controller via api after build, and you will see the environment variable log.

Please tell me why.
https://github.com/yj2dev/Lightning-marketplace-Clone
[image: app.module.ts]

[image: talk.controller.ts]

[image: user.controller.ts]

[image: product.controller.ts]

[image: build env list]

https://github.com/yj2dev/Lightning-marketplace-Clone

Answer (score 0):

just don't use `process.env` directly whenever possible. Use some provider like `ConfigService` from `@nestjs/config`. [Read the docs site](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). Otherwise you'll need to use [`dotenv`](https://npmjs.com/dotenv) like any other nodejs project